# imagebutton not displaying image while image link without extension stored in database

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton

i am using this code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("photo", "~/gallery/thumbs\\{0}") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("ProductID", "gamedetails.aspx?ProductID={0}") %>
```

within a datalist.

it displaying other information but not the image

Comment: You need to be more precise. Add some more explanation and maybe some code. This is just to vague.

Comment: Please add your full code of your image button, then others can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your markup to:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("photo", "~/gallery/thumbs/{0}") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("ProductID", "gamedetails.aspx?ProductID={0}") %>
```

Notice I changed `\\` for `/`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've initialized all attributes other then ImageSrc, probably )